# Ranking System with multiple boolean values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a List of service providers.  Each service provider offers a different set of services.  These services are represented in a SQL database as boolean values.

The user will determine which of these services they require from a service provider as search parameters (checkboxes) in the View.  My goal is to return a list of service providers based on the user's selection and order theses service providers accordingly.  Say the user wants 4 services, I want the service providers with those 4 services to be on top, those with 3 of 4, next, and so on.

I'm having trouble thinking of the best way to do this.  I'm using MVC2 with Linq.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the service providers that has the services flag true putting these flags in an OR condition. When you select a service provider you can calculate the number of service flags that are true. So you have a list of new entities, every entity contains the service provider and the count of the flags setted as true. Now you can order this list by the flags count.